# Install DSPManager on a non-CM Rom

Tags: cyanogenmod, audio, system-apps, equalizer

I would like to install the app DSPManager from Cyanogenmod on my Nexus 4 running ParanoidAndroid.

I grabbed the newest CM and extracted "/system/app/DSPManager.apk" and "/system/lib/soundfx/*" and copied the files onto my phone. I also changed permissions to "rw-r--r--", then I rebooted and could choose the new Equalizer in the Settings (in Sounds).

However changed Settings did just apply for the next song (not the currently playing) until I started DSPManager again...

What is the proper way to install DSPManager on a non-CM Rom, are there other rom-related things I need to change?

How can I get DSPManager to work on my Setup?

PS: I use the Apollo Music Player

PS2: I'm also open to source changes if necessary, but this might not belong on this site!

Comment: DSPManager may be depending on CM specifics hence the settings are not applying...? And yes by the sound of it, you'd need to modify the ROM to cater for that :)

Comment: Have you removed all the other EQ apps?  They might be interfering.

Comment: Yes i did! << 5 more to go

Comment: Oh if anyone could help :/

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you have to chmod rwx-rx-rx? (IE: 755, execute permissions for all users) so that Android can actually run the DSPManager APK/app? Or is this not the case on Android?

Comment: Yes it was also chooseable as Music Effects and startable...

Answer (score 1):

Post #8 on [this forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2174813) has a flashable DSPManager zip file that apparently the user reports worked with Paranoid. If anything, you should also look into flashing [Beats Audio](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2135538) which will give you just as good (if not better) equalizer settings.